# como puedo hacer para que se cargue un puntaje especifico en unity en cierto nivel

Tags: unity

estoy teniendo un problema con un proyecto de unity y necesito solucionarlo pronto, necesito que al si termina el nivel 1 con un puntaje de 1 y en el nivel 2 se consuigue un punto mas (osea queda en 2) al reiniciar el nivel se vuelva a tener 1.  estoy usando playerperf y e intentado de todo pero solo e logrado se que reinicie el puntaje a 0 pero eso no me sirve para el proyecto que quiero hacer

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué intentaste? Podrías utilizar un arreglo o un diccionario para guardar lo que quieras de cada nivel.

Comment: use playerperfs para guardar los datos pero no me funciono